# Copy .txt files from docker container to host

Tags: dockerfile, docker-cp

So I have a docker container with .txt and .csv files in it. I need to copy these to host. But I only need to copy files .txt files. The command `sudo docker cp -a env1_1:/path/*.txt .` does not seem to work. Is copying files of a specific types possible using docker cp? I am unable to find any alternatives for now.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) *does not support glob patterns*, and as an aside, container paths are *absolute*:

> The `docker cp` command assumes container paths are relative to the container’s `/` (root) directory. This means supplying the initial forward slash is optional […]
>
> Local machine paths can be an absolute or relative value. The command interprets a local machine’s relative paths as relative to the current working directory where `docker cp` is run.

However, one may devise a workaround, relying on [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), and a manually crafted shell command relying on the `tar` command on both sides (assuming it is available in the image):

```
sudo docker exec env1_1 sh -c 'cd /path && tar cf - *.txt' | tar xvf -
```

or if need be:

```
sudo docker exec env1_1 sh -c 'cd /path && tar cf - *.txt' | ( cd /dest/path && tar xvf - )
```

Here, the special filename `-` denotes STDOUT (or respectively STDIN).

Usual disclaimer: the final `tar` command will *overwrite without further notice* the selected files in the current folder (or `/dest/path` in the second example).